# React/Jest: How to mock functions come from 3rd party packages

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm pretty new to creating unit tests with Jest. I'm trying to write tests  for a component that uses a 3rd party package, which grabs applanga (translation) keys.

One thing to note also, is that the function is a HOC, which I feel makes this a bit trickier to mock. Some errors I get are `translate is not a function` or `can't perform getState of undefined` Any pointers much appreciated!

Edit: after playing around a bit, I realized all I needed was to mock a few functions. One issue I'm now running into is being able to find stateless components. Below, you can see from the console, it printed out the elements, but instead of `BannerText` like I expected, it printed `Component`.

Code (some code removed for brevity)

```
import { withTranslate } from 'senf-translations';

export const BannerText = ({ index, children, translateRaw }) => (
    <div>
        <h4>
            {translateRaw(`store.banner-item-1`)}
        </h4>
    </div>
);

const BannerItem = props => (
    <div>
        <div>
            <BannerText {...props}/>
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default withTranslate(['store'])(BannerItem);
```

Test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import BannerItem from '../src/modules/banners/BannerItem';

describe('<BannerItem />', () => {
    const mock = jest.fn();
    const props = {
        translateRaw: mock,
    };
    let component;

    it('render banner item', () => {
        component = shallow(<PureBannerItem {...props} />);
        console.log(component.debug());

        expect(component.find('BannerText')).toHaveLength(1);
    });
});
```

Console.debug() output

```
<div className="fela-gzvaff">
  <div className="fela-10318hh">
    <Component translateRaw={[Function]} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the content of `component.debug()` ? And why would you expect your component to have zero `h4` elements ?

Comment: @klugjo type on my part. I updated my post with the error log as well

Comment: @klugjo so it seems the component wasn't even rendering, but once i mocked a function, the console logged the component structure. Now it seems it can't find the rendered component I'm looking for.

Comment: what are you trying to test ? I suggest you test the `translateRaw` and `withTranslate` in isolation. Then you can export you `BannerItem` and test that directly

Comment: @klugjo I want to test to check the existence of `BannerText` component. From my understanding, since `BannerText` is stateless, it's rendering as `<Component />`, so not sure how to test if my component is rendering.